# Modify Windows Form with treeview or radiobutton

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm creating a GUI and I would like an app that changes on based which item in a treeview or which item is selected on a radio button.

I know how to know which item is selected, but how do i change the interface based on the item?

What should I try? Multiple panels? Some hidden?

Imagine the app like and MMC, the right side changes based on what do i select on right.

I used something like `Button1.Visible = true`  and `Button2.Visible = false` in the event, but how do I group the elements in the right side?
In the desingner mode I will see every object overlapping others?

Comment: I would have a single panel for the content pane.  Then create two user controls, create a NEW instance of the right one when an item is selected, dispose of the current one (if there is one in the panel), and parent the new one to the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to something like a menu (menu options on the left; when one is clicked, the right side of the window is filled with the corresponding settings), just create a separate control for each 'window' (non-technical use of the word) on the right. When an entry on the left side is selected, handle the Click event by calling BringToFront() on the corresponding control in the right panel.

If you're not referring to a menu, and are instead referring to something much more granular (where each selection on the left side operates on the same central display-unit, and each selection may only affect one small portion), then divide the central display-unit into panels, one for each unit that may be affected by the left-side selection, and Show and Hide them according to the left-side selection.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like what I need. How do I create this controls? In the toolbox I dont see them http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/3255/controlh.png.

Comment: They're essentially new code units that you'd add to your project. 'Control' can refer both to the atoms of a form (buttons, groupboxes, etc), as well as larger composites (such as a button + combobox, or five textboxes organized vertically). Once you've made one of these controls (say, by 'Add New Control' in the Solution Explorer), and once that control has been built, you can add it to your form in exactly the same way that you would add any of the other .NET-provided controls.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to handle this is to have a panel on the right side of the screen, and each of the different views have their own UserControl created. Then when the tree view selection changes, you clear the children of the panel, create the relevant UserControl instance, add it to the panel, and set its Dock to Fill. Something like the pseudo-code below:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Clear();
        UserControl uc = new MyUserControl();
        uc.DataToShow = (MyObject)treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag;
        uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel1.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
```

Comment: What about using somehting like tabs? This is not possible uising the Designer, rigth?

Comment: You can do it in the designer, but there are two main problems. Firstly, most people that do it that way then want to hide all of the tabs except the current one. WinForms doesn't do that properly (although you can fudge it a bit). Secondly, if you have a lot of tabs they all get created when your program starts up, thereby slowing it down.